# How to determine a statistical model to fit into data based on distribution

Tags: time-series, distributions, modeling, matlab

I am trying to learn to fit data into models.The data is multi dimensional with `n` observations for each of the `k`dimensions.I went through the link [Link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16022/how-to-find-a-fitted-statistical-model-to-a-series-of-data) but in my case the data is multi dimensional having several columns of data. The data is obtained from each temporal frame of a video representing features such as pixel coordinate (x,y) ,speed,acceleration along x and y component for 20 videos each of 200 frame duration.Can somebody please explain how to do this and whether it is possible to do linear or nonlinear regression models.

1. Is it necessary to find the distribution of the data before fitting into a model? Is there a criteria for selecting a model based on distribution?
2. Should the number of variables in the model equal to the number of columns of data?If so then it will not be an AR model, I think. I should then go for higher dimensional polynomials where each variable will represent a feature vector.Or are there other linear or nonlinear regression models?I am particulary interested in NARMAX modelling but do not understand the complexities.
3. After fitting into the model,how do I test the "goodness of fit" ?

An illustration with an example of a model will be really helpful.

Comment: "*I believe it is necessary to find the distribution of the data*" --- whereas I believe it's impossible to find the distribution of the data, and in any case, usually pointless since -- for the models you mention -- the unconditional distribution of the data is not something assumptions apply to. What are your response variables, and what are your predictors?

Comment: I do not know that for the data models mentioned,if it is necessary to find distribution of the data.But,in general for any kind of data is it not necessary to find the mean and variance before modelling?All I am asking is given a data set,how to begin modelling.The data set is obtained from here http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~jcorso/r/actionbank/ and I wanted to do model based action recognition.Could you provide guidelines as to what models can be done & how to go about it?

Comment: The issues are (i) You can't know what the distribution of the data *is*, only more or less what it isn't; (ii) the assumptions only apply to the response (the DV); (iii) the assumptions don't apply to the raw response (the unconditional $y$), but to the conditional response (for which you examine residuals -- which you only have *after* you have fitted your model). I'm not sure why you'd think it necessary to find means and variances before modelling (I might typically do so, but not because one must do so).

Comment: "*Could you provide guidelines as to what models can be done & how to go about it?*" seems to go beyond the 'can be answered in a few paragraphs' format of the stackexchange network. Can you reword your questions more specifically? Explain in your question what you want to achieve? Please note that most statisticians will be quite unfamiliar with your particular application. I will say that "Is it necessary to ..." is a better way to start than "I think is is necessary to ..."; the first invites an answer ("no, it isn't"), while the second invites a debate on why.

Comment: I have re-worded the question as per your suggestions,please have a look.

Comment: Minor clarification - my earlier comment was referring to distributional assumptions (which only apply to response variables) - it was not to imply that no assumptions at all apply to the predictor variables ($x$'s,IVs).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That's an easier question to answer. Can you clarify the form of model you have in mind? What is the model trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it necessary to find the distribution of the data before fitting into a model?

No; it's neither necessary (since the unconditional distribution of data doesn't relate to the assumptions for the kind of models you mention) nor possible (you can't identify what distribution data come from, though you might be able to rule some out).

> Is there a criteria for selecting a model based on distribution?

The distributional assumptions, if any, apply only to the responses (not any of the predictors). If you want to use (multivariate) linear regression or nonlinear regression, there's an assumption about the conditional distribution - and even then an assumption about the functional form of the conditional distribution really only when constructing confidence intervals or doing hypothesis tests. And even then, in large samples only the prediction interval would be particularly sensitive to moderate deviations from the assumption. (Assumptions like homoskedasticity and independence matter more than the distributional form, however.)

(If you were doing something like a factor analysis, you could have an unconditional-distribution assumption there.)

> Should the number of variables in the model equal to the number of columns of data?

I don't think this is necessary. It depends on your model.

> If so then it will not be an AR model, I think.

I don't see how that relates to the previous issue. The time series aspect is new with your edit, previous you looked to be asking about linear and nonlinear regression.

If your problem is a time series one, your tags should include 'time-series'.

> I should then go for higher dimensional polynomials where each variable will represent a feature vector.

I don't even understand what you're saying now. This is because you didn't explain your situation or underlying conceptual models nearly clearly enough. Most people here will not know what you're doing. I certainly didn't even realize from your original question you wanted to ask about *time series* models. I have no idea what you mean by 'feature vector' in this context.

You jump from mentioning a few of your variables to 'can anyone explain how to do this'... without really explaining what you are trying to achieve. You seem to think we can read your mind or that we know what you know. We really don't.

> Or are there other linear or nonlinear regression models?

Certainly there are other models than AR or models based on polynomials.

> I am particularly interested in NARMAX modelling but do not understand the complexities.

I'm unfamiliar with the various issues with fitting nonlinear time series models with exogenous inputs like NARMAX ([Wikipedia on NARX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_autoregressive_exogenous_model) for anyone else unfamiliar); if you were considering this kind of analysis, your tags should *at least* include 'time-series'.

> After fitting into the model,how do I test the "goodness of fit" ?

Why *test*, specifically, rather than assess?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I found this paper which closely deals with what I want to do "Recognition of Human Gaits" and "Learning Stable Non-Linear Dynamical Systems
with Gaussian Mixture Models". In this paper, the joint angle values are captured and  a dynamical model is constructed from it.This is what I wish to do.HEnce,the question about distribution assumption.So,I wanted to know the preliminaries like how would each of the feature column which are recorded for each time instant be given as input into a regression model.